# Can a String variable hold data which is equal to a 10 MB text file?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible for a string to hold around 250000 ( a round figure) lines of data in a text file ?

Comment: Do you really need that big a string? Else a stream-reader might be the better approach to whatever you want to do.

Comment: 250000 lines of data ina text file

Comment: I guess its possible, but definitely not recommended!

Comment: I think java has (or maybe had) the default memory size of 32MB, adjust it higher with run properties -Xms128M -Xmx128M or higher, otherwise if you have few of these Strings or work with them, you will receive MemoryOut.

Comment: Yes, if you have enough of heap space,memory it can,very very easily.Also see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141739-max-length-of-a-string.html .It will clear your doubts.

Comment: 10 MB in a string does not seem a pratical implementation for any requirement. Why not use a stream ?

Comment: What happened when you tried?  You can create a String with up to 2 billion characters.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary The default size for the server VM is 1/4 of the main memory size.  If you have 4 GB for example, it will be 1 GB.  If you are still running on 32-bit windows perhaps it's time for an upgrade ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I had no problem with 64bit win, my previous workplace had :D Anyways thanks for info, our first bigger project standalone java app had the problem of OutOfMemoryError and this solved.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Newer versions of Java 6 and 7 use 32-bit references by default for up to 32 GB of heap so there is little disadvantage in using a 64-bit JVM (unless you only have 32-bit DLLs) BTW I am looking at a new 64 GB PC, for a home office.  That much memory will cost me £280. :O

Comment: @peter-lawrey A string containing the whole 237000 lines was created. Since the maximum size a string can hold is [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) i.e. 2^31-1 bytes which is 2GB-1byte ~ 2GB , a String can hold **1400 Kindle e-book** contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the maximum size a string can hold is [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) i.e. 2^31-1 bytes which is 2GB-1byte ~ 2GB , a String can hold **1400 Kindle e-book** contents

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get a String of length [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (always 2147483647 (231 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are backed by char[] arrays, so they are limited to the size of an array structure. An array can hold Integer.MAX_VALUE elements and it also depends on how much memory you've allocated to the JVM. So, in theory a String can be upwards of two billion characters